# <0xC0000005> Error with inserting into linked lists

Tags: c, list, pointers, memory

I am having trouble resolving an error in the function below.  The function's purpose is to insert numbers into a linked list in ascending order.

This function works fine when the list is empty/inserting the first node, but I get the error `Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>` when it tries to insert a node afterwards.

```
Node *orderedInsert(Node *p, int newval)
{
    Node* q = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    q->data = newval;
    if(p == NULL || newval <= p->data)
    {
        q->next = p;
        return q;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* tmp = p;
        while(tmp != NULL && tmp->data <= newval)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        q->next = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = q;
        return p;
    }
}
```

I realize that a 0xC0000005 error represents an access violation; and while trying to debug this I noticed that accessing `tmp->next` would not give me any intended results: I'm guessing something is off with my `tmp` node, I just don't quite know what and how to fix it.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are inserting one past where you need to insert.  Which means that if the node you are inserting has the largest value, you will get to the end where `tmp` is NULL, and then you will try to set `tmp->next` to `q`.  You might want to use a `prev` pointer that is one element behind `tmp`, so you can insert at `prev` instead.

Comment: Sweet. That was exactly my problem. Thank you for the great explanation!